# Combining districts in shapefile to produce custom regions in R

Tags: r, region, tmap

I am working with a dataset that uses custom regions ("North", "South" and "West") and I would need to plot them onto a map with tmap.
As a first step, I assigned the different districts to the respective regions and merged them into the shapefile and then merge the data with the shapefile.

```
customregion <- data.frame(district = c("Area1", "Area2", 
"Area3", "Area4")

region = c("North", "North","South","South"))

shape <- sf::read_sf("./gadm40_ABC_1.shp") # read shapefile

shape <- merge(shape, customregion, by = "NAME_1")

mapdata <- merge(shape, data, by.x = "NAME_1", by.y = "district")

tm_shape(data) +
  tm_fill(midpoint = NULL, "indicator", palette="Reds", style="cont") +
  tm_text(text = "maplabel")
```

Not unsurprisingly, I get a map like the one below, where the regional data is plotted into each district border.

It seems I would need to aggregate the different borders in the shapefile into proper regions.

How do I do this in R?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WryPs.png
```

Comment: What info does `data` have? Is `data` or `mapdata` the file you want to change?

Comment: @aldo_tapia: in data I have stored the indicator data I need for the map together with the region. It looks like this:
district      indicator
North        46
South        50

I need to aggregate the shapes in mapdata so that I only have 1 shape for North and 1 for South.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geoprocess you are searching is called *Dissolve*. According to [GIS WIKI](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Dissolve):

> **Dissolve** is an application of the conceptual operators that aggregates features often referred to as 'Merge' or 'Amalgamation.' It
> is a process in which a new map feature is created by merging adjacent
> polygons, lines, or regions that have a common value for a specified
> attribute.

This fits in your description. With `sf` objects, you can use `dplyr` functions in order to apply this geoprocess.

Some reproducible data:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(rnaturalearth)

v <- ne_countries()

v <- st_as_sf(v)

v %>% filter(region_un == 'Africa') -> v

plot(v[,'subregion'])
```

[image]

For dissolve geometries, the first step is grouping by one (or more) attribute, then summarise geometries:

```
v %>% group_by(subregion) %>% summarise() %>% plot()
```

[image]

There are some issues with this example’s geometries. You can use `sfheaders` library for improving the output:

```
library(sfheaders)

v %>% group_by(subregion) %>% summarise() %>%
  sf_remove_holes() %>% plot()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot - exactly what I was looking for!!